# Counting emails in outlook by date

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-office

I Have the following code to count the number of emails in a outlook folder.

```
Sub HowManyEmails() 
Dim objOutlook As Object, 
objnSpace As Object, 
objFolder As Object 
Dim EmailCount As Integer 
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    On Error Resume Next    
    Set objFolder = objnSpace.Folders("Personal Folders").Folders("Inbox").Folders("report's").Folders("Customer")    
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then    
    Err.Clear   
    MsgBox "No such folder."    
    Exit Sub    
    End If

EmailCount = objFolder.Items.Count    
Set objFolder = Nothing    
Set objnSpace = Nothing    
Set objOutlook = Nothing

MsgBox "Number of emails in the folder: " & EmailCount, , "email count" End Sub
```

I am trying to count the emails in this folder by date so i end up with a count for each day.

Comment: This clearly isnt [tag:vbscript] - do you mean VBA from inside Outlook?

Comment: It might be easier to link to Excel or to use ADO to run a query : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/275262

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might try it with this code:

```
Sub HowManyEmails()

    Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim EmailCount As Integer
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

        On Error Resume Next
        Set objFolder = objnSpace.Folders("Personal Folders").Folders("Inbox").Folders("report's").Folders("Customer") 
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        MsgBox "No such folder."
        Exit Sub
        End If

    EmailCount = objFolder.Items.Count

    MsgBox "Number of emails in the folder: " & EmailCount, , "email count"

    Dim dateStr As String
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim msg As String
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set myItems = objFolder.Items
    myItems.SetColumns ("SentOn")
    ' Determine date of each message:
    For Each myItem In myItems
        dateStr = GetDate(myItem.SentOn)
        If Not dict.Exists(dateStr) Then
            dict(dateStr) = 0
        End If
        dict(dateStr) = CLng(dict(dateStr)) + 1
    Next myItem

    ' Output counts per day:
    msg = ""
    For Each o In dict.Keys
        msg = msg & o & ": " & dict(o) & " items" & vbCrLf
    Next
    MsgBox msg

    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objnSpace = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetDate(dt As Date) As String
    GetDate = Year(dt) & "-" & Month(dt) & "-" & Day(dt)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks that work great, one question is there any way for this info to be saved to an csv file?

Comment: @fmunkert: +1 Nicely done :) Just one suggestion. Don't use `Exit Sub` after `MsgBox "No such folder."` Do a proper clean up :) Remember you still have Outlook running in the background ;)