# Outlook vba count folder items between dates

Tags: vba, count, outlook, directory

I've been modifying some code (fmunkert, 2012) I originally found on this site, of which originally counted the number of items (emails) in a set folder.

Then producing two message out puts (message 1:total emails in folder, Message 2:list of the by date).

I have modified the module to count two set folders and combine them into one set of overall stats for each of the two messages.

As these folders cover a whole year I want to restrict the second message to only show the dates for the last 30 days, I've tried to set the area I believe will check this.

However I just get all the dates showing 1 item apart from about 3 date show a random number.

My fully modified code

```
Sub InboxEmails()

Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As MAPIFolder, objFolder1 As MAPIFolder, objFolder2 As MAPIFolder
Dim EmailCount1 As Integer
Dim EmailCount2 As Integer
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")


    ' Verify exisitence of 2013 Actioned / Updated Folder
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objFolder1 = objnSpace.Folders("test@sample.net").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Alico Metlife  Actioned / Updated").Folders("2013 (Actioned / Updated)")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    MsgBox "2013 Actioned / Updated Folder Not Found."
    Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Verify exisitence of 2013 IRs Raised Folder
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objFolder2 = objnSpace.Folders("test@sample.net").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Alico MetLife IRs Raised").Folders("2013 (IRs Raised)")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    MsgBox "2013 IRs Raised Folder Not Found."
    Exit Sub
    End If


'All folders are present, OK to continue.

EmailCount1 = objFolder1.Items.Count
EmailCount2 = objFolder2.Items.Count

MsgBox "Number of chargeable emails: " & EmailCount1 + EmailCount2

Dim dateStr As String
Dim myItems1 As Outlook.Items
Dim myItems2 As Outlook.Items
Dim dict As Object
Dim msg As String
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set myItems1 = objFolder1.Items
Set myItems2 = objFolder2.Items
myItems.SetColumns ("SentOn")


' Determine date of each message:
For Each myItem In myItems1
    dateStr = GetDate(myItem.SentOn)
    If Not dict.Exists(dateStr) Then
        dict(dateStr) = 0
    End If


    dict(dateStr) = CLng(dict(dateStr)) + 1

Next myItem

' Determine date of each message:
For Each myItem In myItems2
    dateStr = GetDate(myItem.SentOn)
    If Not dict.Exists(dateStr) Then
        dict(dateStr) = 0
    End If

    dict(dateStr) = CLng(dict(dateStr)) + 1

Next myItem


' Output counts per day:
msg = ""
For Each o In dict.Keys
    msg = msg & o & ": " & dict(o) & " items" & vbCrLf
Next
MsgBox msg

Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objnSpace = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Attempt version 1

```
If Not dict.Exists(dateStr >= IsDate(Now) - 30) Then
```

Attempt version 2

```
If Not dict.Equals(dateStr >= IsDate(Now) - 30) Then
```

Attempt version 3

```
If Not dateStr >= IsDate(Now) - 30 Then
```

I'm sure pretty sure it will be this area I need to alter, however I just can't get to work. I'd be grateful to know where I'm going wrong with this.

EDIT:
I have been doing more research into this and know I'm on the right track, here is my latest code

```
Dim dateStr As Date
Dim myItems2 As Outlook.Items
Dim dict As Object
Dim msg As String
Dim lastweek As Date
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set myItems2 = objFolder2.Items
myItems2.SetColumns ("SentOn")

'Determine date of each message:
For Each myItem In myItems2
dateStr = GetDate(myItem.SentOn)

lastweek = Date
If Not dict.Item(dateStr) >= ((lastweek) - 30) Then
dict.Remove myItems2.myItem
Else

dict(dateStr) = CLng(dict(dateStr)) + 1

End If

Next myItem
```

While I have used watches on each line to ensure it passes the date through as expected however this still doesn't go to the else part of the if statement.

'dateStr' shows the date of the items, while '(lastweek) - 30' shows the date of 30 days previous of the current date.

With this being in the if statement I'd expect it to goto the else part for the statements those dates, where the dates are within the 30 days. However this doesn't occur, and I can't see why not.

References
fmunkert (2012), [Counting emails in outlook by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189681/counting-emails-in-outlook-by-date) [online] (access 03/2013)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a good place to put this code. It counts inbox items by date.

```vb
Sub UserCount()

    ' Put your email, and start date here.
    InboxEmails "user@domain.com", "1/1/2014"

End Sub

Sub InboxEmails(strEmail As String, strStartDate)

    Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As MAPIFolder, _
    objDict As Object, strDate As String

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objnSpace.Folders(strEmail).Folders("Inbox")

    Set myItems = objFolder.Items
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' Cache the SentOn column.
    myItems.SetColumns ("SentOn")

    ' Count messages by date.
    For Each myItem In myItems

        ' Only look for emails, other object types do not have a SendOn property.
        If myItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" Then

            ' Strip time from datetime.
            dateStr = FormatDateTime(myItem.SentOn, 2)

            ' Only find messages after startDate.
            If CDate(dateStr) > CDate(strStartDate) Then

                    If Not dict.Exists(dateStr) Then
                        dict(dateStr) = 1
                    Else
                        dict(dateStr) = CLng(dict(dateStr)) + 1
                    End If

            End If

        End If

    Next myItem

    ' Print the results to the Immediate Window (Ctrl + G).
    For Each o In dict.Keys
        Debug.Print o & vbTab & dict(o)
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally stumbled across where I had been going wrong, and simply found that this line of my code was at fault

```
If Not dateStr >= ((lastweek) - 30) Then
```